# Execute function if and only if a certain amount of time has elapsed since subscription with RxJS

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I am making an API call through an Observable. If this API call takes more than 200ms, I would like to show a loading screen (by assigning 'true' to my 'loading' variable), otherwise I don't want to show anything, in order to avoid a blink on screen.

Is there an RxJS operator capable of doing this ?

```
this.apiService.get(`/api/someEndpoint`)

// I hope for something like
.triggerIfAtLeastThisAmountOfTimeHasElapsed(200, () => {
  this.loading = true;
})

.subscribe(response => {

  // Process the response

  this.loading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this so you can use for example this:

```
const api = this.apiService.get(`/api/someEndpoint`);
const loading = Observable
  .timer(1000)
  .do(() => loading = true) // show loading
  .ignoreElements(); // or `filter(() => false)

Observable.merge(api, loading)
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(() => loading = false);
```

Comment: If the request completes before the timer, the 'do' will still trigger and set the loading state to true.

Comment: That's true, so you can just add `.take(1)` and the chain will be disposed after a single emission.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines of Martin's response, this is an example that should simulate your context

```
const obs1 = Observable.timer(200).take(1);

const apiSubject = new Subject<string>();
const apiObs = apiSubject.asObservable();
const apiExecutionElapsed = 1000;

const obs3 = Observable.merge(obs1, apiObs);

let loading = undefined;

obs3.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (loading === undefined && data === 0) {
      loading = true;
    } else {
      loading = false;
    }
    console.log('loading', loading);
  },
  console.error,
  () => {
    loading = false;
    console.log('loading', loading);
  }
)

setTimeout(() => {
  apiSubject.next('I am the result of the API');
  apiSubject.complete()}, apiExecutionElapsed)
```

If the execution of the api (`apiExecutionElapsed`) takes longer than the configured timer (200 ms in this case) you see the `loading` flag to become first true and then false. Otherwise it remains always false.